# Recursive ordinals and the minimal standard model of ZF

Tags: lo.logic, set-theory, model-theory

1. Does the minimal standard model of ZF contain all recursive ordinals or is it limited (probably by the proof theoretic ordinal of ZF as I suspect but cannot prove)?
2. Paul J. Cohen's definition of the minimal standard model for ZF.(http://www.ams.org/journals/bull/1963-69-04/S0002-9904-1963-10989-1/S0002-9904-1963-10989-1.pdf) is iterated through all ordinals. What is the least ordinal it must be iterated up to generate the minimal standard model?

Comment: Re: (1): Unless I'm gravely mistaken, the minimal transitive (probably shouldn't say "standard" model of ZF contains far more than just the recursive ordinals: every *first-order definable* well-ordering of $\omega$ will wind up in it, by replacement. The key point is that since the model is well-founded, the natural numbers of the model are just the standard naturals, so if an ordinal $\alpha$ is definable in the real universe by a first-order formula, that formula will still define that ordinal in the minimal transitive model.

Comment: (Of course, the language of ZF is not that of arithmetic, so "first-order definable" takes some interpretation; but the point stands.)

Comment: Noah, the arithmetic ordinals and inded, the hyperarithmetic ordinals, are the same as the computable ordinals, so you don't get anything new this way.

Comment: . . . Yes, of course. (This is what I get for doing math before I've woken up fully. :p)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The minimal transitive (or synonymously, standard) model of ZF is $L_\alpha$, where the ordinal $\alpha$ is chosen to be smallest such that $L_\alpha\models\text{ZF}$. Since ZF proves that $\omega_1^{CK}$ exist, and the recursive ordinals are absolute between $V$ and $L_\alpha$, it follows that $\omega_1^{CK}<\alpha$. So the answer to question 1 is yes.

The ordinal $\alpha$ is precisely the number of times you have to iterate Gödel's definable power set operation in order to build the minimal transitive model, and I don't know any simpler definition of $\alpha$ than: *the height of the minimal transitive model*.

Meanwhile, $\alpha$ is a fairly small countable ordinal, if it exists, and furthermore countable in $L$. An upper bound for complexity is provided by the fact that there is a $\Delta^1_2$ definable relation on $\mathbb{N}$ with order type $\alpha$, simply by noting that we may define the least $L$-code for such a relation, using at most that complexity.

Comment: Besides, given any model of $\mathsf{ZF}$, even if ill-founded, some of its ordinals are standard. The height of this segment is either $\omega$ or an admissible ordinal.

Comment: "Meanwhile, $\alpha$ is a fairly small countable ordinal" --- is there any countable ordinal which is *not* fairly small, among all countable ordinals?

Comment: You are right! Any particular ordinal is small. But I think being countable in $L$ makes it look especially small, if one is inclined toward $0^\sharp$ or large cardinals, and the fact that it has a $\Delta^1_2$ definition is something vaguely resembling the OP's expectation that it might be limited in terms of the complexity of the smaller ordinals.

Comment: Thank you.  Very interesting, like all of your comments.